# Using Optionals and forEach in Java 8, check for empty object

Tags: java-8, java-stream, option-type

I would like to use Optionals with forEach in my example below, and am not sure about the correct approach.

Basically the functionality is as follows:

```
List<Long> myList;
List<Long> myResultList;

myList = getValues_A();

if (null != myList && !myList.isEmpty())
    return;

for (Long singleVal : myList) {
     List<Long> tempList = getValues_B(singleVal);
         if (null != tempList && !tempList.isEmpty())
              myResultList.addAll(tempList);
}
```

So I simple retrieve some data into myList, check if there is some value returned, and if so, I use the result to again retrieve data and put it in a final result list.

My idea with Optionals:

```
List<Long> myList;
List<Long> myResultList;

myList = getValues_A();

if (null != myList && !myList.isEmpty())
    return;

myResult.forEach(itemToCheck -> Optional
      .ofNullable(getValues_B(itemToCheck))
      .ifPresent(myResultList::addAll));
```

**Questions:**

The first part:

```
myList = getValues_A();

if (null != myList && !myList.isEmpty())
    return;
```

Is there any way to use Java 8 Optionals instead?

I.e.

```
myList = getValues_A();

if (!Optional.ofNullable(myList).isPresent())
  return;
```

But this would only check for null and not if the object was empty (for which I also want to return). Can this be extended with a size check of the object within the Stream?

Also, misusing Optional's isPresent as a nullcheck only is bad coding practise I guess. Any other ideas?

The second part:

I assume that even empty objects will be attempted to be added to myResultList? Can this be somehow prevented in a similar approach, i.e. check if size = 0 within the stream?

```
myResult.forEach(itemToCheck -> Optional
      .ofNullable(getValues_B(itemToCheck))
      .ifPresent(myResultList::addAll));
```

Small sidenote: I can't use isEmpty(Object object) of org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils as I'm with version < 3.9.

Comment: `if (null != myList && !myList.isEmpty())`: this should simply be deleted. A method that returns a List should never, ever return null. If it does, then you should fix that method instead of circumventing the bug by checking for null everywhere. And checking if the list is empty is unnecessary too. Just iterate on the list: if it's empty, then nothing will happen, and that's what you want.

Comment: And Optional is not a new fancy tool to check for null in a different way. it's used as a return type to signal that a method can return "empty", and make sure the code deals with this empty case.

Comment: ideally getValues_A() should return Optional and it should return Optional.Empty() for Null case .. so you never have to deal with null issues

Comment: @JBNizet “Optional is not a new fancy tool to check for null in a different way.” +100! Thanks for fighting the good fight!

Comment: @RahulSawant no, ideally, `getValues_A()` should just return an empty list, when there are no elements. So no special case is ever needed.

Answer (score 0):

I also think it is worth mentioning that besides whole reusing Optional is not good thing in any possible case(with which I agree). We also see in this approach that we create empty list and then altering its state by adding new elements. I thing if we can we should always avoid such solutions. Much cleaner approach is to instantiate list with its elements while declaring.

Answer (score 0):

For getting rid of first part, you can make the getValues_A() function to return an Optional or an empty list instead of null.It make no sense to make any processing with Optional in this method.

Second part written with stream :
  `List<Long> myResultList = myList.stream().map(singleVal -> getValues_B(singleVal)).filter(Objects::nonNull).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Each steps explained:
   1. `map(singleVal -> getValues_B(singleVal))`  - each element of the list will be processed and you'll get a List as result for each.
   2. `filter(Objects::nonNull)`  - remove empty lists
   3. `flatMap(List::stream)` - from stream of `List<Long>`,you'll obtain a stream of Long
   4. `collect(Collectors.toList())` - collect all resultList.

Answer (score 0):

You may take advantage of the orELseGet() API of the Optional and the map/flatmap APIs of the stream to simplify your code.

```java
List<Long> resultList = Optional.ofNullable(getValues_A())
                                .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
                                .stream()
                                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                .flatMap(l -> Optional.ofNullable(getValues_B(l))
                                                    .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
                                                    .stream()
                                                    .filter(Objects::nonNull))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```